# Syntax on Switch Discrepancies

Tags: java, switch-statement

According to the java documentation a switch statement example could look like this:

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

I wrote a test program:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Practice2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = in.nextInt();
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1: x = 4;
            System.out.println("Hey");
            break;
        case 2: x = 5;
            System.out.println("You");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("as;ldfj'");
        }
    }
}
```

If I select 1 it chooses case 1. If I select 2 is chooses case 2. It won't actually test for the x = 4 and the x = 5. I am using Eclipse if that makes any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would it test for `x = 4`? What do you think `=` does? How do you think case statements are evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = 4` isn't a case in the switch statement, it's an assignment.

If you want a case for `x == 4`, you will need `case 4:` in the switch statement.